# How do I find the distribution of sum of Two Dependant Random Variables?

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, mathematical-statistics, random-variable

So, I have this question (as seen in the picture) and I am curious how would I go about approaching it. Initially, I thought to use convolution but I don't think this is a valid approach because after finding the marginals, I found that they didn't satisfy a condition of independence. What are other things I could do? I read about change of variables, but I don't really have a great understanding of it... if someone could provide an example or something on how to do the question, it would be great[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC7SJ.png)